# Saltstack: ignoring result of cmd.run

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to invoke a command on provisioning via Saltstack. If command fails then I get state failing and I don't want that (retcode of command doesn't matter).

Currently I have  the following workaround:

```
Run something:
  cmd.run:
    - name: command_which_can_fail || true
```

is there any way to make such state ignore retcode using salt features? or maybe I can exclude this state from logs?

Answer (score 13):

Use [`check_cmd`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#check-cmd) :

```
fails:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /bin/false

succeeds:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /bin/false
    - check_cmd:
      - /bin/true
```

Output:

```
local:
----------
          ID: fails
    Function: cmd.run
        Name: /bin/false
      Result: False
     Comment: Command "/bin/false" run
     Started: 16:04:40.189840
    Duration: 7.347 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              pid:
                  4021
              retcode:
                  1
              stderr:

              stdout:

----------
          ID: succeeds
    Function: cmd.run
        Name: /bin/false
      Result: True
     Comment: check_cmd determined the state succeeded
     Started: 16:04:40.197672
    Duration: 13.293 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              pid:
                  4022
              retcode:
                  1
              stderr:

              stdout:


Summary
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=2)
Failed:    1
------------
Total states run:     2
```

Comment: check_cmd doesn't exist anymore on 2017.7.0

Comment: @Dereckson No, it's still there?  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2017.7/ref/states/requisites.html#check-cmd  I just retested the snippet above with 2017.7.2 and it still works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care what the result of the command is, you can use:

```
Run something:
 cmd.run:
    - name: command_which_can_fail; exit 0
```

This was tested in Salt 2017.7.0 but would probably work in earlier versions.